# How do I get the namespaces of an assembly and not its dependencies?

Tags: c#, reflection, namespaces, assemblies

How do I get the namespaces of an assembly and not of its dependencies?

For example, if I get the namespaces using

```
assembly.GetTypes().Select(t => t.Namespace).Where(n => n != null).Distinct()
```

would I not get the namespaces of the dependencies of that assembly as well?

How do I distinguish between the 2?

I am loading the assembly via Assembly.LoadFrom(path) and I understand that it automatically loads the assembly's dependencies. For the solution, do I have to load the assembly in a way that the dependencies are not loaded? If yes, how do I do that?

Also, I do not have any control over the Assembly creation, like adding an empty class etc.

EDIT: correcting an example

Comment: That should only give you the namespaces of types *in* that assembly. Can you give an example of why you think it includes dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Linq.Expressions` is in fact in the `EntityFramework.dll`.

Specifically, the following classes are in that DLL, under that namespace:

- `System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor`
- `System.Linq.Expressions.Internal.Error`
- `System.Linq.Expressions.Internal.ReadOnlyCollectionExtensions`

Also, you should also be seeing `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` because `EntityFramework.dll` defines the class `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute`.

** Note, I am inspecting EntityFramework **6.0.0.0**

To more directly answer your questions:

> How do I get the namespaces of an assembly and not of its dependencies?

`assembly.GetTypes().Select(t => t.Namespace)`

> Would I not get the namespaces of the dependencies of that assembly as well?

No.

> How do I distinguish between the 2?

N/A

> For the solution, do I have to load the assembly in a way that the dependencies are not loaded?

No.

> If yes, how do I do that?

N/A

Comment: Thanks for correcting. Doesn't the question still stand though?

Comment: No.  See edit.  You are not getting types from dependent assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

`Assembly.LoadFrom()` does not load the assembly's dependencies, so your code as it is will do exactly what you want.

Now, let's pretend it does load dependencies; again: it does *not*.

Assuming you somehow got all of the types in all of the loaded assemblies (a highly contrived situation), you could select only the types in the target assembly, and then apply your "distinct code."

```
types
    .Where(x => x.GetName().Name == "Your.Assembly.Name")
    .Select(t => t.Namespace)
    .Where(n => n != null)
    .Distinct()
```

Comment: Apparently it does load the dependent assemblies, but the object itself refers only to the specific assembly. Apologies for the half-researched question.

Answer (score 2):

Loading an assembly does "load" all dependent assemblies into memory, but the `Assembly` *object* you're dealing with only pertains to the assembly that you're explicitly loading, so calling `GetTypes` only loads the types defined *in that assembly*.

So if you're getting namespaces you don't expect, it's because there *are* types *in that assembly* in the namespace (types in a namespace don't all have to be contained in one assembly)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.